# PHP - Print position of user in ranking page

Tags: php, html

I am making a ranking page where I am displaying the username by descending order. The names already appear in the correct order but I am having trouble showing the position on the user, like 1º place, 2º place...
This is my code (simplified):

I tried to do a for loop (in every place I could think of) and print the value of $i, but it doesn't seem to work, either $i has always the same value in every position or all of them in the same position.

```
<?php 
for($i=0;$i<8;$i++){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $names =$row['username'];
            ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="image">
                        <svg></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2><?php print $i; // print the positions ?></h2>
                        <p><?php print $names ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>

<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: You are executing the `while` 8 times. That's why `$i` is always `0` during the first loop. You don't see the output from the following iterations because the mysql resulset is already at its end (thus `mysqli_fetch_assoc` always returns `false`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SQL orders the users in the correct order, then instead of having a loop, just have a counter and increment it each time (using `$i++`)...

```
<?php 
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $names =$row['username'];
            ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="image">
                        <svg></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2><?php print $i++; // print the positions ?></h2>
                        <p><?php print $names ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$counter=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $names =$row['username'];
            $counter++;
            ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="image">
                        <svg></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2><?php echo $counter; ?></h2>
                        <p><?php print $names ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please tell why this anwers the question. Read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).